# angular2 array push object in in object

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a tree structure where the root node is named "OR". It should have "AND" node as its children, which in turn should have "OR" nodes as its children and so on...
Can someone tell me whats wrong with this code?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let i of data1">
            {{i.name}}
            <button (click)="add(i)">Add node</button>
            <button *ngIf="i.categories.length >0" (click)="delete(i)">Delete
                nodes</button>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of i.categories">
                    <my-app></my-app>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    name:string;
    key: string = 'categories';
    data1 = [
        {
            name: "OR",
            categories: []
        },
    ];

    add(data){
        var newName = data.name="AND"? "OR" : "AND"
        var entry = { name: newName, categories: []}
        data.categories.push(entry);
    }

    delete(data) {
        data.categories = [];
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't know, what doesn't work about it? What happens when you trace through it with the debugger? Do you get a run-time error? A compile-time error? Or it runs with incorrect results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mi5JhO5Y4bZF94FYn2od?p=preview) demo of exactly what you want to achieve.

You were on the right path by using recursion you just needed to pass the new category as `Input` to the `my-app` component so it can render it.

Here is the complete code for the component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div> 
        {{dataRef.name}}
        <button (click)="add(dataRef)">Add node</button>
        <button *ngIf="dataRef.categories.length >0" (click)="delete(dataRef)">Delete 
        nodes</button>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of dataRef.categories">
              <!-- you just needed to pass dataRef to keep track of categories -->
              <my-app [dataRef]="item"></my-app>
            </li>
        </ul>

      </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataRef: any;

    name: string;
    key: string = 'categories';
    // I don't think we need an array, an object would suffice
    data1 = {
        name: "OR",
        categories: []
    };

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("old", this.dataRef);
        // use this.data1 for the first time as this.dataRef will be undefined
        this.dataRef = this.dataRef || this.data1;
        console.log("new", this.dataRef)
    }

    add(data) {
        var newName = data.name === "AND" ? "OR" : "AND"
        var entry = { name: newName, categories: []}
        data.categories.push(entry);
    }


    delete(data) {
        data.categories = [];
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanx, that worked...
was just wondering what changes should be made if I wanted the delete button beside every node when it is spawned and which would result in deletion of that node itself

Answer (score 0):

It should be data1 instead of data

```
add(data){
   var newName = data.name==="AND"? "OR" : "AND";
   var entry = { name: newName, categories: []}
    data1.categories.push(entry);
}
```

Comment: `data.name==="AND"? "OR" : "AND"` for ternary operator too.

Comment: I want to add a new object in the categories of the data object which is passed as the parameter

Comment: you cannot add a object to a object

Comment: I want something like this...

    data1 = [
    {
     name: "OR",
      categories: [{
                       name: "AND",
                       categories: []
                    }]
    },
];

Comment: `data1` will be undefined and you'll get a `RefererenceError`. Did you mean `this.data1`? But `data` is getting passed to `add`, so `data` should be fine...right?